# Problems setting Autofac to work with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper, autofac

I use the latest version of Automapper in my application, together with Autofac. I set the configurations and profiles and unit tested all my profiles with `AssertIsConfigurationValid()` and everything is working fine.
However, when I use the mapper
within my application I get a `"Automapper missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping"` exception only when running from code, I suspect it is something to do with how I set the mapper to work with Autofac:

```
   // This is how I register my mapper with Autofac
    public class ModelsMapperModule : Module
    {
        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes().AssignableTo(typeof(Profile)).As<Profile>();

            builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                foreach (var profile in c.Resolve<IEnumerable<Profile>>())
                {
                    cfg.AddProfile(profile);
                }
            })).AsSelf().SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve)).As<IMapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }   
    }


// Here is a simple version of my objects and mappings:

public class LetterDomain
{
    public List<StationDomain> Stations {get; set;}

    public string Title {get; set;}

    public int Id {get; set;}

    public int TimeCreated {get; set;}

    public string File {get; set;}

    public bool IsSecret {get; set;}
}

public class StationDomain
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Owner {get; set;} 

    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class LetterDto
{
    public DestinationDto Dest {get; set;}

    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class DestinationDto
{   
    public List<StationDto> Stations {get; set;}
}

public class StationDto
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

public class MyProfile : Profile
{   
    protected override void Configure 
    {
        CreateMap<StationDomain, StationDto>()

        CreateMap<LetterDomain, DestinationDto>();

        CreateMap<LetterDomain, LetterDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<DestinationDto>(src)));
    }   
}


public void MyMethodInsideApplication(LetterDomain letter)
{
   // Exception is thrown here
   var dto = _mapper.Map<LetterDto>(letter);
}
```

I'm trying to map `LetterDomain` to `LetterDto` in my application and it tells me that the configuration of `LetterDomain` to `DestinationDto` is missing, although I definitely created the mapping..

Would really like for some help here..

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I just wanna add that all other mappings that doesn't use the static Mapper.Map<> inside their configuration profile work good in the application

Comment: In which class does the `MyMethodInsideApplication` method live? Was such class created via the container? Can you show how?

Comment: It's a singleton, it is resolved in startapp

Comment: Where are you using the static `Mapper.Map<>` method? can you show that code?

Comment: In my mapping from LetterDomain to LetterDto inside MyProfile class

Comment: Is it that line that throws the exception?

Comment: I think the problem is that you configure a mapper instance (not the static Mapper), and then you use the static Mapper, which is not configured.

Comment: If this is the case, then one way to fix the problem is to configure the static mapper instance and then configure autofac to use that instance. There might be a way without the static mapper but I am not sure how. Is there a way to access the mapper instance from the profile? I am not sure.

Comment: Not I can't use the mapper instance there.. Do you know of a way to avoid it? I don't want to use the static mapper in my application code

Comment: By the way, do you really need `Mapper.Map`? Can you use `.ForMember(x => x.Dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))` in your case instead of `.ForMember(x => x.Dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<DestinationDto>(src)));`?

Comment: I think the MapFrom is to provide a value with the same type and just use it. It won't prefrom a complex mapping as I expected Mapper.Map<> to do

Comment: Did you test it? I think that `MapFrom` would actually do mapping.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you didn't specify how `DestinationDto.Name` should be populated when mapping from `LetterDomain` to `DestinationDto`.

In other words, `LetterDomain` has no `Name` property, so no automatic mapping is possible for that property.

Comment: My bad, posted wrong..fixed now. I'm sure all the mapings are fine.. I tried it in unit tests and it's good.. It gotta be something to do with my application code - specifically the usage of the static mapper after register insance mapper

Comment: I thought it might have just been your posting since you did say the validation succeeded. Maybe this answer would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35565524/cannot-resolve-automapper-imapper-using-automapper-4-2-with-autofac/35566443#35566443

Comment: Although the registration with Autofac seems okay, because I do use the mapper successfully in other parts of the application where the Configuration map doesn't use the static Mapper.Map<> method.
Regardless, is there a reason to register both IMapper and IMappingEngine?

Comment: I would definitely try leaving out `IMappingEngine`. Unless you have a class that depends on it, I don't think it's needed. (I think I just included it because the OP of that question had it in his code.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can't use both static and not static version of the mapper at the same time (unless you create both static and not static map, but is useless); by the way, you don't need to use

```
CreateMap<LetterDomain, LetterDto>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<DestinationDto>(src)));
```

to apply the map, just

```
CreateMap<LetterDomain, LetterDto>()
        .ForMember(x => x.Dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src));
```

The map will be applied automatically, if exists.

You can also simplify the mapping process a bit, if you want:

```
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var profiles =
            from t in typeof (MapperModuleRegistration).Assembly.GetTypes()
            where typeof (Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t)
            select (Profile) Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var profile in profiles)
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(profile);
            }
        });

        builder.RegisterInstance(config).As<MapperConfiguration>();
        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper()).As<IMapper>();
    }
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had my mapping profiles in a separate dll that was not referenced by any of my other projects. By adding a reference to my mapping profiles .dll it fixed my problem.